# RDP not going to multiple Screens

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to use multiple monitors with an rdp session on Windows 10(host), the source is on Win 7(guest) and a Hyper-V vm.

When I exec from cmd the following code `mstsc.exe /span` it works, but not my desired result.

However, when I try `mstsc.exe /multimon` nothing happens, and this is the desired effect.

Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Comment: So after looking inside the vm, it looks like it doesnt have a 2nd monitor available.  This vm is hosted on my pc, so why wouldnt it have 2 monitors?  And how can i add the 2nd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `mstsc.exe /?`:

> /multimon -- Configures the Remote Desktop Services session monitor layout to be identical to the current client-side configuration.

So to have two monitors in your RDP session while using this switch, you'll need two monitors set up on the RDP server (the VM in this case).

**Edit:**

User noted (after answer was posted) their VirutalBox tag was wrong, and that they're actually using Hyper-V as the hypervisor.

*There is (currently) no way to add a second virtual display to a Hyper-V VM*; So you're stuck using the `mstsc /span` option to utilize multiple monitors on the RDP client.

**Orginal Answer (VirtualBox):**

To add a second monitor to a VirtualBox VM:

- Ensure the VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed in the guest OS.
- Power down the VM.
- Right-click the VM and choose "Settings..."
- Choose "Display" in the left-hand panel.
- Turn up the "Monitor Count" to `2` (you may need to assign more virtual Video Memory for each monitor you add).

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is this done in Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: You tagged it VirtualBox, so I figured you meant VirtualBox.  Now I note you ALSO tagged it Hyper-V.  Perhaps edit your question to spell out exactly which Hypervisor you're using, and which OS the VM's guest and host are running.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. I meant to tag virtualization :/